# VSTS - pool Hosted VS2017 - how to restart built-in agent after replace

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Could you please let me know how to restart built-in agent after replace with another private? Step to reproduce
- Download agent 
- run config, replace built-in agent with local

Then, pool hosted VS2017 will use local agent.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you install a private agent, you need to switch your build/release definitions to point to your agent queue. You have no control over the hosted agent.

Answer (score 0):

VSTS Hosted agents (Hosted, Hosted VS2017 and Hosted Linux Preview) are deployed automatically by VSTS on server. So you’d better not replace the hosted agents with private agent.

If you wrongly replace Hosted VS2017 agent by accident, unfortunately, you can’t recovery it as original one for now.

I posted a problem [VSTS Hosted agent replaced by private agent and can not recovery](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/86564/vsts-hosted-agent-replaced-by-private-agent-and-ca.html), you can follow up.

The work around now is using a private agent and install the require softwares you need on the agent machine.